# How to process a large number of records in aspnetboilerplate framework

Tags: entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate, boilerplate

Used following syntax to insert 500 rows, it takes a lot of time. How to insert/update/delete a large number of records in the boilerplate asp.net core framework. Is there any option in ABP to work with large data?

```
using (var unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin())
{

  Context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
  foreach (var element in list)
  {
      _repository.Add(element);
  }
  unitOfWork.Complete();
}
```

Comment: [https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Entity-Framework-Core#batch-operations](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Entity-Framework-Core#batch-operations)

Answer (score 1):

If you are wondering about deadlocks and transaction is not a issue for you if something fails. Than you can do it: `TransactionScopeOption.Suppress`. Please see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscopeoption?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) or [this](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Unit-Of-Work?searchKey=TransactionScope#unit-of-work-scope) one.

```
 using (var unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
 {

    Context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    foreach (var element in list)
    {
      _repository.Add(element);
    }
    unitOfWork.Complete();
 }
```